# Split Joomla Database result in 3 columns

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I am trying to split the mysql query result using joomla sql syntax and stuck as to how I can split the same in three columns.

my query for which I am getting the result in single column is like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "select m.member_name name from member m,club_name c where pst in (6,35,39,40) and c.id=m.club_name and c.id = '{club_name___id_raw}'";
if (!$query) {
echo 'Could not run query:' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$i = 0;
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$text1 .= '<table style="border:1px solid silver;padding:2px;">';
$text1 .=  "<tr><th>Past President</th><th>Past President</th></tr>"; 
foreach ($results as $result) {

$text .= "<tr><td>"; 
$text .=  $result->name;
$text .=  "</td></tr>";
$text .= "<br/>";
}
$text .=  "</table>";
return $text1 . $text;
```

I am getting the result like

```
 Past President
 Jaydeven 
 Ashok 
 surendra 
 Narendra 
 Gopal
```

**I want the result like**

```
Past President Past President Past President
Jaydevan       Ashok          Surendra
Narendra       Gopal
```

How can modify the above query to get the result as shown

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I somewhat achieved what I wanted. I have edited the query like below:

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
//var_dump($results);exit;

$text1 .= '<table style="border:1px solid silver;padding:2px;width:800px;">';
$text1 .=  "<tr>"; 

$i = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
if ($i % 3 === 0) {
$text .= "</tr><tr>";
}
$text .= "<td>";
$text .=  $result->name;
$text .=  "</td>";
$text .= $i++;
//$text .= "<br/>";
}

$text .=  "</tr></table>";
return $text1 . $text;
```

Only problem I am now facing in my result set is I am getting a 
string of number i.e. 0123456
if the result contains 7 items, which couldn't hide.
Thanks.